# RealmList in RealmObject. How to persist order?

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

I have a `RealmObject` with a `RealmList` as one of its field.

```
public class ToyMaker extends RealmObject {
    private RealmList<Toy> toyList;
    ...
}

public class Toy extends RealmObject {
    ...
}
```

1. Will the ordering of `Toy` in `toyList` be persisted when written to Realm and reading it back?
2. If ordering is not persisted by Realm, how can i achieve this manually given that

   A. I cannot add additional fields (e.g. index) in `Toy` class (a `Toy` can have many `ToyMaker` so an index field in `Toy` is not feasible.

   B. The ordering is in the order that `Toy` is added to `toyList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `RealmList` is ordered, so case #1 is correct. Just add them in the order you want, and that order will be persisted.

In general though, ordering is not guaranteed, so creating 2 objects in the Realm does not imply an order:

```
realm.createObject(Person.class, 1);
realm.createObject(Person.class, 2);

// Doing this is not guaranteed to return Person:1
realm.where(Person.class).findAll().first()

// Always use a sort in queries if you want a specific order
realm.where(Person.class).findAllSorted("id", Sort.ASCENDING).first();
```

Comment: I wasn't able to find this piece of information on realm docs, I think it will be great if you could add this in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: I am using public <E extends RealmModel> List<E> copyToRealmOrUpdate(Iterable<E> objects) to store a list to realm but list order is not kept. How can I persist the list order? Thanks!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce is there any way of updating the order after having added the items, rather than removing and re-adding?

Comment: In a RealmList? Nope. When I wanted things to be ordered, I typically stored a field called `rank`, but of course that wouldn't work if your item is in multiple lists.